# a-frame entity-positioning and rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr

Sadly I am not familiar with the positioning and rotation of entites in 3D space, so I want to create a function that positions an entity with easier to understand parameters like:

```
createEntity(vertical, horizontal, distance)
```

for

```
<a-entity position="-2 0 -2" rotation="-10 30 0"></a-entity>
```

where vertical and horizontal are float-values between 0 and 360 and distance is a float where 0 is position "0 0 0" and as higher the value than farther the entity goes.

the rotation should face the camera at init.

are there helper-function for the calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the [Spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) to position the elements, and the [look-at](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/look-at) component to rotate the objects towards the camera.

I'm not aware of any helpers, but it's quite easy to do this with a custom component, like this:

```
// Register the component
AFRAME.registerComponent('fromspherical', {
  // we will use two angles and a radius provided by the user 
  schema: {
     fi: {},
     theta: {},
     r: {},
   },
   init: function() {
     // lets change it to radians
     let fi = this.data.fi * Math.PI / 180
     let theta = this.data.theta * Math.PI / 180

     // The 'horizontal axis is x. The 'vertical' is y. 
     // The calculations below are straight from the wiki site.
     let z = (-1) * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(fi) * this.data.r
     let x = Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(fi) * this.data.r
     let y = Math.cos(theta) * this.data.r
     // position the element using the provided data
     this.el.setAttribute('position', {
       x: x,
       y: y,
       z: z
     })
     // rotate the element towards the camera
     this.el.setAttribute('look-at', '[camera]')
   }
 })
```

Check it out in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/by7u1hem/) fiddle.

---

The calculations are in a different order than on the wiki website. This is because in aframe the XYZ space looks like this:

[image]

The camera is looking along the negative Z axis upon default initialization.

---